# Error al crear un nuevo registro relacionado

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla relacionada a otra PRODUCTOS Y MARCAS,
lo que pasa es que cuando creo marcas y productos  todo va bien. El problema es cuando elimino una marca y creo otra, y al momento de crear un nuevo ´producto con algún rol me manda el error siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi controlador tengo:

```
public function create()
{
    $marks = Mark::lists('name','id')->prepend('Seleccioname la Marca');
    return view('product.create')->with('marks',$marks);

}
```

Y en la vista:

```
{!! Form::select('marks_id',$marks,null,['id'=>'marks_id','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Tengo estos registros en marks con sus id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando veo el código fuente me salen en value una lista desde 1 hasta n que no son correctos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es un rol?

Comment: Perdón, era marca.

Comment: Eso es aveces lo malo de usar blade, puedes usar solo HTML y solucionarías tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando el método `prepend()` para agregar el valor `Seleccione la marca`, pero no estás especificando el segundo parámetro, que es la llave de dicho valor. Cuando no la especificas, este método utiliza la función [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) de PHP, la cual reinicia los índices numéricos del arreglo / array.

`Illuminate\Support\Collection`

```
/**
 * Push an item onto the beginning of the collection.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @return $this
 */
public function prepend($value, $key = null)
{
    $this->items = Arr::prepend($this->items, $value, $key);

    return $this;
}
```

`Illuminate\Support\Arr`

```
/**
 * Push an item onto the beginning of an array.
 *
 * @param  array  $array
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @return array
 */
public static function prepend($array, $value, $key = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        array_unshift($array, $value);
    } else {
        $array = [$key => $value] + $array;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

---

Después de ver la referencia de los métodos en cuestión, la solución sería:

```
$marks = Mark::lists('name','id')->prepend('Seleccioname la Marca', 0);
```

---

Otra solución rápida para no agregar nada al array sería simplemente utilizar el atributo `placeholder` de la etiqueta html del select y poner la cadena `Seleccione la marca` ahí.